# vaadin 22 fails to load views with /* servlet pattern

Tags: tomcat, servlets, vaadin

I'm trying to configure the vaadin 22 servlet to handle requests to /*

They aim is to deploy vaadin into tomcat's root context so that I can have paths like:

`https://myapp.com/Login`

Currently, I have paths like:

`https://myapp.com/mycontext/ui/Login`

So let's start with the /ui

If I have the webservlet as detailed below the following url works:

`https://myapp.com/mycontext/ui/Login`

webservlet with /ui/*

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns =
{ "/ui/*"}, name = "MyApp", asyncSupported = true,  loadOnStartup = 1, initParams =
{
        @WebInitParam(name = "org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor", value = "dev.myapp.servlets.AtmosphereFilter"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "closeIdleSessions", value = "true"),

        /// changed this when we release.
        @WebInitParam(name = "productionMode", value = "false")

})
```

If I change the webservlet to just /* and try with the following url:

`http://localhost:8080/mycontext/Login`

the vaadin page fails to load

webservlet with /*

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns =
{ "/*"}, name = "MyApp", asyncSupported = true,  loadOnStartup = 1, initParams =
{
        @WebInitParam(name = "org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor", value = "dev.myapp.servlets.AtmosphereFilter"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "closeIdleSessions", value = "true"),

        /// changed this when we release.
        @WebInitParam(name = "productionMode", value = "false")

})
```

The failure is in two stages.
I see a network request for http://localhost:8080/mycontext/Login
Which succeeds and returns the standard vaadin javascript boot loader:

```
<!doctype html><!--
This file is auto-generated by Vaadin.
-->
<html lang="en"> 
 <head>
  <script initial="">window.Vaadin = window.Vaadin || {};window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors = window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors || [];const browserConsoleError = window.console.error.bind(window.console);console.error = (...args) => {    browserConsoleError(...args);    window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors.push(args);};window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {const location=source+':'+lineno+':'+colno;window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors.push([message, '('+location+')']);};window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', e => {    window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors.push([e.reason]);});</script>
  <script initial="">window.Vaadin = window.Vaadin || {};window.Vaadin.TypeScript= {};</script>
  <base href="."> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

I then see a second request to mycontext/Login which includes the JSESSIONID.
This completes with a 200 but the body is empty.

The webapp then reports a vaadin error (in the little vaadin debug widget)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (http://localhost:8080/mycontext/VAADIN/build/vaadin-2-398f0dc50fc60665f718.cache.js:1:1)
```

and

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 2 failed. (missing: http://localhost:8080/mycontext/VAADIN/build/vaadin-2-398f0dc50fc60665f718.cache.js)
```

If I wget this url it returns the expected vaadin script:

```
head vaadin-2-398f0dc50fc60665f718.cache.js 
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([[2],{

/***/ "../target/flow-frontend/FlowBootstrap.js":
/*!************************************************!*\
  !*** ../target/flow-frontend/FlowBootstrap.js ***!
  \************************************************/
/*! exports provided: init */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
```

Addendum:

I'm running jdk 17, tomcat 8.5

@Tatu-lund got me closer however I'm now getting a push error which results in the web site displaying the offline-stub.html every second attempt (or there abouts).

```
Logged XXX@YYY.com.au into session com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession@2e51025c

[Atmosphere-Shared-11] ERROR com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler - Exception in push connection
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:328) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:291) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:503) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.73]
```

I've now tried using tomcat 9 but with the same results.
I've also added the @Push annotation to my AppShellConfigurator.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the *frontend* folder to `urlPatterns` as well:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/ui/*",
        "/frontend/*" }, asyncSupported = true, initParams = {
...
}
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. I'm guess you had a type and meant "/*" rather than "/ui/*". Which works sometimes and then doesn't. It looks like it might now be a push issue. Will add the  error to the original question.

Comment: I've been experimenting and its the inclusion of /frontend/* which causes websockets to start failing.